# Как зафиксировать размер и положение div при зуме на моб устройствах

Tags: javascript, css

Как сделать фиксированный div с шириной 50% и высотой 50% от видимой области окна  браузера.

Нужно что бы блок оставался на месте при скролле.
Нужно что бы размеры блока были всегда одинаковые. Независимо от зума на мобильных устройствах.

Тоесть, юзер зумирует пальцами страницу, контент сайта увеличивается/уменьшается а этот div висит поверх всего сайта и всегда занимает 50% ширины и высоты экрана независимо от зума.

Comment: может, position: fixed, height: 50vh, width: 50vw; ?

Comment: или может даже height:50%; width:50% сработает при фиксированном позиционировании

Answer (score 0):

```
.block{
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: black; /*чтоб было видно блок*/
}
```